# Pow Function Different Output pow(10,2) and pow(10,n) where n = 2?

Tags: c, floating-point, compiler-optimization, pow

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){
    int n = 2;
    int z = 2*pow(10,n);
    int y = pow(10,n);
    printf("%d %d" , z , y);

    return 0;
}

Output is : 199 99
```

When I use `2` instead of `n` like `int z = 2*pow(10,2)` `int y = pow(10,2)`.

```
Output is 200 100
```

I know how to eliminate this problem.

It gets eliminated if instead of integer `z` and `y` are float.

I want to know how really C does casting integer to float and other conversions?

Why does using `2` instead of `n` eliminate the problem?

**Update**

This Question [What is happening here in pow function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42164550/what-is-happening-here-in-pow-function?noredirect=1&lq=1) Talks About This Thing and has some pretty good answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42164550/what-is-happening-here-in-pow-function?noredirect=1&lq=1